# How to Order By list inside list using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to Order by "SortKey" first list and second list inside first list, but I can't do it. Please get me your advice how to order lists using LINQ.

```
//Get Data and put in myList
List<Group1> myList = GetData(); 

//Sort
//Visual studio do not get compilation error but this code doesn't working at the run-time.
var SortedData = myList.Select(x => x).OrderBy(x=> x.SortKey).ThenBy(y=> y.Group2.OrderBy(x=> x.SortKey)).ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class Group1
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Sortkey {get;set;}
   public List<Group2> {get;set;}
}
public class Group2
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Sortkey {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: this code compiles? `public List<Group2> {get;set;}`

Comment: @Jens Yes this "public List<Group2> {get;set;}" compiles. I need only Order list inside list, Models and Code is only visual method to explain situation.

Comment: @Tim I have already changed "Categories" to Group2

Comment: @AvtandilKavrelishvili: no, you still have a property without name: `public List<Group2> {get;set;}`. According to your LINQ query that should be `Categories`. Now you have changed the query so it should be `Group2`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test this code and everything is working well.

```
 var result = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ToList();
                foreach (var item in model)
                {
                   item.Group2 = item.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: So this is basically the second aproach of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30869271/284240). If so you should consider to accept it ;)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter yeah :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot re-order the innerlist with a LINQ query. The only way is to create a new ordered list. I suggest to use a simple loop and `List.Sort`:

```
List<Group1> myList = GetData();
myList.Sort((x1, x2) => x2.SortKey.CompareTo(x2.SortKey));
foreach(Group1 item in myList)
{
    item.Group2.Sort((x1, x2) => x2.SortKey.CompareTo(x2.SortKey));
}
```

If you want to use LINQ (`List.Sort` is more efficient):

```
List<Group1> myList = GetData().OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ToList();
foreach(Group1 item in myList)
{
    item.Group2 = item.Group2.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ToList();
}
```

But why can't you order the lists in `GetData`?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to do it in "one" line. what do you think about my answer? would be happy to hear your opinion

Comment: @JensHorstmann: a LINQ **query** should not have side-effects. An `OrderBy` that modifies the collection is clearly a side effect ;)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: thank you for your advice.  I solve this after your answer. you can see my code below.

Answer (score 2):

I am not good with LINQ and i haven't tested this solution
but what about this:

**HINT:** This solution may not be good, because it has side effects (see comment on other answer)

assuming you have these classes:

```
public class Group1
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Sortkey {get;set;}
   public List<Group2> Categories {get;set;}
}

public class Group2
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Sortkey {get;set;}
}

// Order first List with the first OrderBy
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(
    x =>
        {
            // x equals a element in the list
            // foreach x you want to sort the second list 
            // and assign it back to x.Categories
            x.Categories = x.Categories.OrderBy(y => y.Sortkey).ToList();
            return x.Sortkey;
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Dear Jens Horstmann, you can't  use return x.Sortkey in linq. you can check it on Microsoft developer's site, but this way is not bad:)

Comment: Oh okay :'D But it think this will compire.. and i was assuming that x => x.SomeThing is an Lamda expression so i could use this lamda to make a delegate with a return